# Angular, Create an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Probably sthg stupid, I would like to create an array of objects like this (*title1, label1, etc* are static) :

```
private productsList: Product[] = [
   new Product('title1','label1'),
   new Product('title2','label2')
]
```

**Result (okay):**

[image]

But when I try to create dynamically this array using a json, despite the array is populated as before, it doesn't work, and I notice that it doesn't look the same.

**here is what I get (NOT OKAY) :**

[image]

**What I tried so far :**

```
 private productsList: Product[] = [];
 constructor(){
    ...
    for (var product in json) {

      var title=json[product]['title'];
      var label=json[product]['label'];

      this.productsList.push(new Product(title,label))
    }
   })
 }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: do you really need to do this - `json[product]['title']`? how about using this - `product['title']`?

Comment: can you show the `json` object?

Comment: Don't see any problem. Please share your `Product` class and *json*. For such scenario, I use `this.products.push(Object.assign(new Product(), jsonObj))`;